# How to list then install in (new) command line sdk's?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

After having downloaded Android sdk tools [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) (at the bottom), (`sdk-tools-windows-3859397.zip`), I'd like to install Android sdk *using command line*.

NB: I don't want to install Android Studio.

I want to install one of these:

- AndroidApiLevel16 Android 4.1, "Jelly Bean", API level 16.
- AndroidApiLevel17 Android 4.2, "Jelly Bean", API level 17.
- AndroidApiLevel18 Android 4.3, "Jelly Bean", API level 18.
- AndroidApiLevel19 Android 4.4, "KitKat", API level 19.
- AndroidApiLevel21 Android 5.0, "Lollipop", API level 21.
- AndroidApiLevel22 Android 5.1, "Lollipop", API level 22.
- AndroidApiLevel23 Android 6.0, "Marshmallow", API level 23.
- AndroidApiLevel24 Android 7.0, "Nougat", API level 24.
- AndroidApiLevel25 Android 7.1, "Nougat", API level 25.

What is the command line, how to list what are the Sdks available?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html

Comment: ..... I've already tried that.... `.\bin\sdkmanager.bat --list` gives me: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema` blabla

Comment: That class has been around since at least Java 7. What JDK is installed on this machine?

Comment: cmd line gives me `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)`

Comment: It's possible that `sdkmanager` does not support JDK 9.

Comment: Very interesting... I had Java 8 then installed Rider update, I guess this one made a Java update... I'll try to uninstall java9 then install java8 I'll tell you

Comment: Ooops sorry I have `Java 9.0.4 (64 bits)`, but `Java SE Develoment Kit 8 Update 151 (64 bits)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've uninstalled all my Java installation, `Java 9.0.4 (64 bits)` and `Java SE Develoment Kit 8 Update 151 (64 bits)`.
Then installed `jre1.8.0_172` and `jdk1.8.0_172`.

Now everything works...